# 2.7 setup script fails under 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

I have a package with an install script that installs fine under 2.7, but the setup script (using setuptools) fails when running it with 3.4:

```
± python setup.py develop
running develop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 45, in <module>
    url = "http:www.planetfour.org",
  File "/Users/maye/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Users/maye/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Users/maye/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 973, in run_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/Users/maye/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/Users/maye/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.7-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 50, in finalize_options
  File "/Users/maye/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.7-py3.4.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 313, in finalize_options
  File "/Users/maye/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.7-py3.4.egg/setuptools/package_index.py", line 269, in __init__
  File "/Users/maye/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.7-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 802, in __init__
  File "/Users/maye/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.7-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 832, in scan
  File "/Users/maye/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.7-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 852, in add
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < NoneType()
(py34)-> [1]
```

What I tried:

- I'm doing this in the same source folder from where I have installed the 2.7 version, is that bad/dangerous? I deleted all *.pyc FWIW?
- I tried 2to3 if it would show any required changes in my setup.py script, but it says none required:

> ```
> ± 2to3 setup.py
> RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
> RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
> RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal
> RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma
> RefactoringTool: No changes to setup.py
> RefactoringTool: Files that need to be modified:
> RefactoringTool: setup.py
> (py34)maye@lunatic|~/Dropbox/src/P4_sandbox on master
> ```

Edit, as motivated by comment:
The only ordering I can find is the `install_requires` line:
    install_requires = ['pandas>='+pandas_version]
with
    pandas_version = '0.13.1'

If that is the culprit, how does one do this correctly in Python 3.4?

Here is the whole setup.py:

```
import ez_setup
ez_setup.use_setuptools()
import sys
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.command.test import test as TestCommand

pandas_version = '0.13.1'

class PyTest(TestCommand):
    def finalize_options(self):
        TestCommand.finalize_options(self)
        self.test_args = ['-v']
        self.test_suite = True

    def run_tests(self):
        #import here, cause outside the eggs aren't loaded
        import pytest
        errno = pytest.main(self.test_args)
        sys.exit(errno)


setup(
    name = "Planet4",
    version = "0.1beta2",
    packages = find_packages(),

    install_requires = ['pandas>='+pandas_version],
    tests_require = ['pytest'],

    cmdclass = {'test': PyTest},

    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            'p4reduction = planet4.reduction:main',
            'plot_p4_imageid = planet4.markings:main',
            ]
    },

    #metadata
    author = "K.-Michael Aye",
    author_email = "kmichael.aye@gmail.com",
    description = "Software for the reduction and analysis of Planet4 data.",
    license = "BSD 2-clause",
    keywords = "Mars Planet4 Zooniverse",
    url = "http:www.planetfour.org",
)
```

Comment: 2to3 isn't perfect; the syntax for ordering is still the same, but the behaviour has changed. See https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Comment: ah, so it must be this line then: `install_requires = ['pandas>='+pandas_version]` with pandas_version = '0.13.1' ? How do I do this correctly in 3.4 then? I can't see any special remarks for 3.4 in the setuptools docs?

Comment: No, this is not an ordering, only string concatenation. Is this a clean virtual environment?

Comment: How is clean defined? It's setup with conda for python 3.4, a few packages came in via pip, and it's activated via the 'source activate <envname>' system. What else can I say?

Comment: But isn't there somewhere an ordering occuring somewhere, when it is being determined if the available pandas version is >= the required one?

Answer (score 1):

The last source line of the traceback:

```
  File "/Users/maye/miniconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.7-py3.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 852, in add
```

If you go to that line and start working backwards you will hopefully find both variables that are being compared -- one of them is a `str`, the other is `None`.  The `None` variable probably got that way from a failed lookup.

Figure out why the lookup failed and perhaps you fix the problem by modifying your `setup.py` -- otherwise you may need to patch `pkg_resources.py` to handle the case where the one variable is `None`.

Digging into the `setuptools` 5.7 version, we find this at the error site:

```
def add(self, dist):
    """Add `dist` if we ``can_add()`` it and it has not already been added
    """
    if self.can_add(dist) and dist.has_version():
        dists = self._distmap.setdefault(dist.key, [])
        if dist not in dists:
            dists.append(dist)
            dists.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('hashcmp'), reverse=True)
```

The last line is where the error occurs -- when `dists` is being sorted.

The `key` being used is `hashcmp`:

```
@property
def hashcmp(self):
    return (
        getattr(self, 'parsed_version', ()),
        self.precedence,
        self.key,
        _remove_md5_fragment(self.location),
        self.py_version,
        self.platform,
    )
```

Which, as you can see, does not return `None`.

---

About the only thought I have left is:  Do you already have a version installed somewhere in your Python path?  If you do, perhaps it's metadata is missing some important piece and that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: Man, and somebody claimed that Python3 error messages have been improved. :(

Comment: I'm using conda virtual environments so there is no other version of it in the path. So you are saying, there's no way hashcmp should return 'None', right? Puzzling. On the other hand, the error message indicates that the comparison fail with trying it with a str(). I don't understand how it can be a string either, as hashcmp returns a big tuple. How would sorting even work with having this big tuple as a key?

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye: `tuple`s are sorted element by element.  Try putting a `print(dists)` right before the `sort` and see what comes up -- hopefully you can track it down from there.

Answer (score -1):

I think this bug might have caused this behavior:

https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/137/typeerror-unorderable-types-str-nonetype

Especially, the following error symptomatic could help others to identify if this is their problem (this using the `conda` manager, but it should be similar with others):

```
conda create -n test-hash python=3 pip
source activate test-hash
pip install requests
conda install requests
pip install anything # <- fails with str < None
```

The problem was, IIUC, that the distutils AND setuptools got now confused by having more than 1 Python Egg in site-packages and could not `sort` them properly when finding what is the most appropriate version to install now.

Two actions helped me to solve this problem:

1. Using setuptools instead of distutils. For this, in `setup.py` I replaced

   from distutils import setup

with

```
from setuptools import setup
```

2. Upgrade `setuptools` to the recently released version 14.3 that solves the above linked hard to reproduce bug.

I was using my `conda` package manager for doing this, but it should not depend on this.

Comment: Updated, hopefully to your liking. Would be nice if you remove the downvote, if you agree.